# Can anyone explain why this brainfuck if/else code doesn't work?

Tags: if-statement, brainfuck

```
// if x = y then {if_code}; else then {else_code}

,>,< / empty memory

[->-<]> / (x)'y

[>->]< / 0'(y-x)

+[
  {if_code}
  ->>
]< / {if x=y then} (0)'0; {else then} 0'y-x'(1)

[
  {else_code}
  [-]
]< / 0'(y-x)

/ empty memory
```

**/** is to show what the memory should look like, **'** is to separate values in the memory, **()** is used to show where the pointer is, **//** is for comments, and **{}** is for descriptions

Whenever I try to run this, no matter what I input, both the if_code and else_code is run.

Comment: I can't, but this is a very nice question for a newbie, and as I wouldn't touch brainfuck with even a very long stick, have an upvote!

Comment: thx for the support

Comment: btw the comments showing the memory show the memory before that line.

Comment: my mistake I was shifting around the comments to make them more clear and ended up doing the opposite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have at least three '-' commands hidden in your "comments".

Comment: Holy I didn't notice that

Comment: Thanks, it was a pretty stupid mistake